# Apple Magic Mouse 2 [A1657] scrolling is not working after macOS upgrade

Tags: mouse, macos, monterey

I've upgraded to macOS Monterey version 12.0.1 (21A559), and scrolling on my magic mouse stopped working. When I switch it off and on again, the mouse works fine, but the problem occurs suddenly without warning. I've tested with another Mac running macOS BigSur with no problem at all.

Comment: Is the problem now gone or does it still occur?

Comment: this problem is still occurring